# If I try joining a server, why does it always say not authenicated to minecraft.net?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Yesterday night, I changed my username to my old MCPE username on the PC, but today, when I tried joining Badlion and Hypixel, it said ''not authenticated to minecraft.net'' Please help.a

Comment: MCPE and the PC versions are different games. Logins to one will not work on the other, unfortunately. If you want to play on the PC, you'll have to purchase the PC version.

Comment: @DanBron He's not trying to connect to a cross-platform server. He changed his username on the PC version to match that of is PE username.

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently changed your name on Minecraft for PC, try logging out from the launcher and then logging in again.